# Having trouble using fluent ui checkboxes with SharePoint boolean or string columns

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have checkboxes on my SPFX (sharePoint framework, ReactJS/TypeScript) created webpart form.
Every time the webpart starts, all the checkboxes are checked (ticked), I want them to be NOT ticked. I have tried both string and boolean columns in SharePoint to store the changes. They will submit to the list correctly (if I change them to ticked/not ticked) but they always launch as ticked!

Here's the state initialisation:

```
 FocusGroups: false,
```

Here's the JSX:

```
<Checkbox label="Focus Groups" checked={this.state.FocusGroups} onChange={this._onFocusGroupsToChange} />
```

Here's the function:

```
private _onFocusGroupsToChange = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement>, isChecked: boolean) => {
 
        this.setState({
        FocusGroups: isChecked,
 
       }, () => {console.log(this.state.FocusGroups, 'state.FocusGroups');});
 
     }
```

I can give it a workaround by converting the isChecked in the function to a string, but this seems unnecessary.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the problem. The default for the Yes/No column in SharePoint is Yes. This is why it was showing as ticked. Setting it to No solved the issue.
Oh the horrors of coding for SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the defaultChecked property:
[image]

```
 <Checkbox label="Focus Groups"  onChange={this._onFocusGroupsToChange} defaultChecked={false}/>
```

If the checkbox is still checked by default, please try to clear the browser cache.

Comment: Hi Amos, I thought this had worked but it hasn't. If I omit checked then it won't allow me to submit to the SharePoint list.

Comment: This might be unrelated, but the SharePoint columns that the checkboxes submit to are Yes/No fields and they are ALWAYS submitting as Yes, despite the checkboxes being blank.